# Designing schema of data with both common and arbitrary attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, schema

I'm not sure if the title actually makes any sense, but here's my general problem:

I have a table that holds information about events across a number of different devices and platforms. I'm not sure how to efficiently design the schema for querying all events, and then querying for specific event information.

I've tried to keep it all pseudo-code below, so if something doesn't make sense with the code, it's just due to me trying to keep it generic.

Here is a contrived example:

```
Event Table:
  int Id
  datetime Occured_On
  uniqueidentifier UserId --> Users table
  int Category (the type of event) --> Categories table
  text Summary (textual summary of the event)
  text EventSource (specifies whether this is a DesktopEvent or MobileEvent)
```

Then each device has it's own set of data for each event. For example:

```
DesktopEvent
  int Id
  int EventId --> Event table
  text Hostname
  text LoggedInUsername

MobileEvent
  int Id
  int EventId --> Event table
  int PlatformId 
  text ESN

...
```

I want to query the Event table for the last X most recent events. Right now I currently have a column specifying the source of the event, so that I can make a 2nd query to the appropriate table.

```
results = SELECT * FROM Event DESCENDING Occured_On LIMIT 5. 

foreach (result in results)
{
    if (result.EventSource == "DesktopEvent")
       data = SELECT * FROM DestkopEvent WHERE EventId == result.EventId

    ...
}
```

This seems very inefficient though.

It's further complicated by there could be many different sources of events, not just 2 (DesktopEvent and MobileEvent) like above. Trying to join across 10+ tables checking for which one is  not NULL seems to be worse than above.

Is there a better way to structure this data? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In data modeling, you sometimes find things that are not utterly different, but also aren't exactly alike. They have some attributes in common, so they're not utterly different. But they each have some unique attributes, so they're not exactly alike.

Attributes that are common to all those things belong together in one table. That table is usually called a supertype.

Each unique set of attributes belongs in separate tables; those tables are called subtypes. In data modeling, "supertype" and "subtype" don't have anything to do with the object-oriented programming concepts that use the same words. Same words, vastly different meanings. Be careful with that.

It sounds like the table "events" is your supertype. "Desktop events" and "Mobile events" are two of several subtypes.

If that's the case, you're probably on the right track. Inefficiency is only apparent, not real. The real truth is that desktop events and mobile events are different things to you, and so they must be stored in different tables. And storing them in different tables makes integrity constraints infinitely simpler to implement. After all, that's what SQL databases are designed to do. Queries can take advantage of indexes.

Normally, a supertype and 'n' subtypes map to 'n' + 1 tables and 'n' views. You have one table for each of the 'n' subtypes, plus one table for the supertype. You'd also build one view for each subtype; each view joins one subtype to the supertype. You'd normally use the views, and not use the subtype tables directly. But you might use the supertype table directly--to get the last five events, for example.

Search SO for the terms supertype and subtype. SO user PerformaceDBA and I have both written about them more than once. (Apologies to others who have weighed in on relational supertypes and subtypes; I have a lot of trouble remembering names.)

Comment: Thank's for confirming what I thought. I think I was trying to convince myself that having so many individual subtypes was wrong. But, given that they are different types, it makes sense to model them differently.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store all such event-specific data in an EAV style table:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Thus, you might just need 2 tables -- the EVENT table and an EVENT_DETAILS table.  For example, if you have a desktop event ID = 12, you might have the following in the EVENT_DETAILS table:

```
1, 12, hostname, myhost
2, 12, loggedInName, myname
...
25, 17, esn, <esn value> 
etc.
```

So you're mixing detailed data for different event types in a single table.  This *can* be more inefficient to query, but it is a simple, well-understand model that lends itself to extensibility and data dynamic treaments/views.

If you need to optimize this sort of thing, you might look at column-oriented DBs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think because some of the subtype attributes are relational, it still makes sense to just use individual tables, so I can keep referential integrity. I hadn't really read up on EAV though, so I appreciate the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a join in SQL instead of doing two queries in your application code.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT de.*, e.* 
FROM DestkopEvent  de , Event e
WHERE EventId == e.EventId
ORDER BY e.occurred_on desc
) 
WHERE rownum < 6
```

The idea is to leave the complexity of query execution to database instead of handling in the application code. In addition, you can add indexes to optimize the query further.
But in essence, if you are looking for optimization - then think database rather than thinking application.